# Abort Trap: when using a Python script with Tkinter and Pyglet

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, tkinter, pyglet

I have written a Python script which uses Pyglet for the main window and Tkinter for an initial GUI window. This script works as expected on Windows, i.e. it shows the Tkinter GUI window and the Pyglet animation. However, it does not run properly on a Mac, I am not able to make both windows work together, they do work separately.

I have found that the error arises when the line `master = Tk()` is executed, if the following libraries has been imported

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import Window, mouse, key
```

The complete code I am using for testing this is:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import Window, mouse, key
from Tkinter import * # for the subject data gui

master = Tk()
```

And the error message I get from it is the following:

```
Python[1359:60f] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10300adb0
Python[1359:60f] An uncaught exception was raised
ython[1359:60f] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10300adb0
Python[1359:60f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10300adb0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8685b7b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff84e2c0f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868b5110 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8682d91f ___forwarding___ + 751
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86829a68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   Tk                                  0x0000000116cc2b24 TkpInit + 545
    6   Tk                                  0x0000000116c389ee Initialize + 1648
    7   _tkinter.so                         0x0000000116af6c0d Tcl_AppInit + 77
    8   _tkinter.so                         0x0000000116af5657 Tkinter_Create + 919
    9   Python                              0x00000001000c2fad PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21405
    10  Python                              0x00000001000c4fb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    11  Python                              0x000000010003eac0 function_call + 176
    12  Python                              0x000000010000ceb2 PyObject_Call + 98
    13  Python                              0x000000010001f56d instancemethod_call + 365
    14  Python                              0x000000010000ceb2 PyObject_Call + 98
    15  Python                              0x00000001000bc957 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87
    16  Python                              0x000000010002285e PyInstance_New + 126
    17  Python                              0x000000010000ceb2 PyObject_Call + 98
    18  Python                              0x00000001000c0c60 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 12368
    19  Python                              0x00000001000c4fb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    20  Python                              0x00000001000c50d6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    21  Python                              0x00000001000e995e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
    22  Python                              0x00000001000e9bfa PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
    23  Python                              0x0000000100100c0d Py_Main + 3101
    24  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 0x0 + 4294971156
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Abort trap
```

I do not understand what this error means, can anyone help me understand what have I done wrong?

Comment: from a python interpreter on osX mavericks, I tried this: import pyglet, open a window, import Tkinter, open a window. I had no issue. What happens if you do the same from your console ?

Comment: @msarch, I get the same error message I copied in my question. I am using osx 10.6, though.

Comment: Maybe is it related with the python version, I would try to force python 32bit with pyglet. You just have to set it this way : `defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes`

Comment: @msarch, forcing into python 32bit does not make any difference, but thank you for the answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I get asked this by my grad student all the time. Especially when they are copying code from the web.

You're almost certainly having a namespace clash.
You are doing an `import *` or importing names such as `Window, mouse, key` from pyglet and then doing an `import *` from tkinter. When using 2 graphics libraries at once, it a good idea to either deal either deal with the full namespace, e.g., referring to things like `pyglet.window.Window` or alias things, e.g., `import pyglet.window as pw` and then using `pw.Window` or `pw.mouse`.

The code you posted generates the same exception for me, but this version completes without an error:

```
# import pyglet
# from pyglet.gl import *
# from pyglet.window import Window, mouse, key
import tkinter  # import *  # for the subject data gui

master = tkinter.Tk()
```

*Note: I used lowercase `tkinter` because I'm using Python 3.6*